# Can GPG change the contents of an encrypted file?

Tags: csv, gnupg

Our company has a vendor which sends a csv that contains commas that are part of the text. This causes columns drift to the right. They claim that they are enclosing those fields in quotation marks (which would resolve the issue) but when we decrypt them using gpg, the quotation marks are being lost.

Is this claim nonsense?

The file is delivered encrypted as a .pgp.

This is the template for the batch file we use to invoke gpg to perform the decryption.

gpg --batch --yes --passphrase {PASSPHRASE} --pinentry-mode loopback -d -o "{OUTPUT}" "{TARGET}"

Comment: "the quotation marks are being lost" as viewed how? in a text editor? or in Excel? the latter is a famous butcher of CSV files. anyway, seems more like a question for Super User than SO.

Comment: Notepad and excel

Comment: If you've checked with a text editor and there are no quotes, there were no quote in the original file. GPG just decrypts it. For something concerned with security to have the ability to modify files as well as just encrypting/decrypting them would defeat the entire point. So, yes, their claim seems like nonsense. You could perhaps put it tactfully by asking where they see quotes, and if it's in anywhere except a text editor, maybe said viewing software is somehow adding them for display.

Answer (score 0):

> They claim that they are enclosing those fields in quotation marks (which would resolve the issue) but when we decrypt them using gpg, the quotation marks are being lost.
> Is this claim nonsense?

Yes because files before encryption and after decryption are identical.

If you want assurance the files are unchanged, have the vendor create a hash (ie, sha256) of the file before encryption and include this hash when he sends you the file.

For example, something like `sha256sum FILE > SHA256SUM.txt && gpg -r USER -e FILE` would produce a SHA256SUM.txt file containing the sha256 hash of FILE and also encrypt FILE with USER's key. The vendor can then send you the SHA256SUM.txt file along with the encrypted file so you can compare it to the hash of the decrypted file.